# Trouble identifying the subject in a long sentence

Tags: grammaire

I am reading *Les foules* by Guy de Maupassant and I find this sentence:

> Toutes ces personnes côte à côte, distinctes, différentes de corps, d’esprit, d’intelligence, de passions, d’éducation, de croyances, de préjugés, tout à coup, par le seul fait de leur réunion, forment un être spécial, doué d’une âme propre, d’une manière de penser nouvelle, commune, et qui ne semble nullement formée de la moyenne des opinions de tous.

I am confused about:

1. where is the subject of *forment*?
2. why we don’t need to put *ont* before *doué*?

Comment: Can you say why you think we need to put *ont* before *doué*. If we knew that, we might be able to clear up your confusion more easily. (And if we did put *ont* before *doué,* what would the subject of the verb *ont* be?) Clearly, you're misparsing the sentence, but I don't see what mistake you're making.

Answer (score 11):

1. The subject of *forment* is *Toutes ces personnes*, i.e. *Toutes ces personnes forment un être spécial*.
2. There is no need for an auxiliary verb before *doué* because *doué* is used as an adjective here, not as a conjugated verb: *un être spécial doué d'une âme propre*.

Answer (score 10):

1. The subject of "*forment*" is "*Toutes ces personnes*":

> Toutes ces personnes côte à côte, distinctes, [...] forment un être spécial

All these people, different from one another, form a single special being.

2. Here "*doué (d'une âme propre)*" means "endowed with (a soul of its own)", "gifted with". Put simply it's a more graceful way to say "having a soul of its own".

Comment: :::: You win ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre à 15 secondes près ^^